# Web Analytics Web Part displaying multiple copies of same document in Top Content List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-analytics

I have added and configured a Web Analytics Web Part in our SP 2010 environment.  The web part is used to display the 10 most frequently viewed documents in the site collection.  However, it appears to be doubling up on the documents.  So if I opened one document 3 times it shows it being opened up 3 times twice.  Has anyone seen this before and know of the cause?  Is it just because it is brand new and hasn't accumulated a lot of information yet?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.  I have posted a pic to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Comment: This type of question is better suited for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com as it relates to an OOTB web part.